# "File was not found" error using Google Cloud and Jupyter Lab

Tags: python, google-bigquery, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab

My code:

```
import seaborn as sns
from google.cloud.bigquery.client import Client

import os
os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'] = "Desktop/Estudos DS/SQL Study/sqlpractice.json"

client = Client()
```

But even with the path correct, the json key correct, I keep getting the following message

`DefaultCredentialsError: File Desktop/Estudos DS/SQL Study/sqlpractice.json was not found.`

Can someone please help?

Answer (score 0):

If you use `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` from local path right?
If it right you need to move your credential into Colab. Colab its doesn't known your local path.